# jquery response.d returns undefined

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a JavaScript method to call all of my ajax calls, please see below.

```
 <script src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
 function PopulateSystemGroup_js() {

            if ($('#<%=ddlComponentGroup.ClientID%>').val() == "0") {
                $('#<%=ddlSystemGroup.ClientID %>').empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Please select</option>');
                $('#<%=ddlFailureCode.ClientID %>').empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Please select</option>');
            }
            else {
                $('#<%=ddlSystemGroup.ClientID %>').empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Loading...</option>');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'VB.aspx/PopulateSystemGroup',
                    data: '{ComponentGroupID: ' + $('#<%=ddlComponentGroup.ClientID%>').val() + '}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(response){
                    OnSystemGroupPopulated(response);
                    },
                    failure: function(response) {
                        alert(response.d);
                    }
                });

            }
        }

function OnSystemGroupPopulated(response) {
        alert(response.d);
            PopulateControl(response.d, $("#<%=ddlSystemGroup.ClientID %>"));
        }


function PopulateControl(list, control) {

            if (list.length > 0) {
                control.removeAttr("disabled");
               alert("here2");
                control.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Please select</option>');
                $.each(list, function() {
                    control.append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
                });
            }
            else {
                control.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Not available<option>');
            }
        }

</script>
```

the above is called as below in html

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
     ComponentGroup:<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlComponentGroup" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
                 onchange = "PopulateSystemGroup_js();">
        <asp:ListItem Text = "Please select" Value = "0"></asp:ListItem>                 
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br /><br />
    SystemGroup:<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSystemGroup" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text = "Please select" Value = "0"></asp:ListItem>                 
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br /><br />
    FailureCod:<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFailureCode" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text = "Please select" Value = "0"></asp:ListItem>                 
    </asp:DropDownList>
     <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick = "Submit" />                
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

The code behind is as follows

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function PopulateSystemGroup(ByVal ComponentGroupID As Integer) As ArrayList
        Dim list As ArrayList = New ArrayList
        Dim strConnString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("con").ConnectionString
        Dim strQuery As String = "select SystemGroupDescription SystemGroup,SystemGroupID from FCR_SystemGroup where ComponentGroupID =@ComponentGroupID Order by SystemGroup"


        Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(strConnString)
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ComponentGroupID", ComponentGroupID)
        cmd.CommandText = strQuery
        cmd.Connection = con
        con.Open()
        Dim sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While sdr.Read
            list.Add(New ListItem(sdr("SystemGroup").ToString, sdr("SystemGroupID").ToString))
        End While
        con.Close()
        Return list
    End Function
```

The above is functions is firing and the data is loaded in the above arraylist, but when it returns to front end, its not filling the data into dropdown.. The alert(response.d) in OnSystemGroupPopulated is returning an undefined. what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you de following with the client one:
1) Make sure your vb code is returning a JSon object (your client side function is specting one)
2) Debug you javascript function before submitting the data (with Chrome Developer tools for example)
2) Try to parse the "response" to json on success (var response= JSON.parse(response)), then you'll be able to access it ass a json object (response.d).

Hope this helps! 
(sorry for my english)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Json.NET to make convert your response to Json, since your ArrayList doesn't make much sense when returned to the client.
http://james.newtonking.com/json

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
```

Example code:

```
Dim list As New ArrayList()
list.Add("foo")

Return JArray.FromObject(list)
```

Comment: Thansk for the suggestion, i downloaded Newtonsoft.Json.Linq, but still the same issue happened..

Comment: Have you debugged both ends? `JArray.FromObject(list)` isn't null on the server side and `response` really is null on the client side? Look at the entire response object and not just `response.d`

Comment: Ok, but is it null server side or only when it reaches the client?

Comment: JArray.FromObject(list) is returning null.. before I used Arraylist and it was filled, but now when i converting Arraylist to JArray, JArray is not filling. while debugging, i got error:   JArray.FromObject(list) 'JArray.FromObject' is not declared or the module containing it is not loaded in the debugging session.

Comment: Could you try the example I provided above. Just fill the ArrayList with a dummy entry `("foo")`, and see if that works. I tried that one myself, and "foo" was returned to the client using JArray.FromObject(list) just fine. It might be a good place to start looking for the problem.

Comment: i tired with adding with a dummy entry ("foo"), but the return value was same error..

Comment: my current code is below:
[CODE]
 <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function PopulateSystemGroup(ByVal ComponentGroupID As Integer) As JArray  
        Dim list As ArrayList = New ArrayList
              
        list.Add("foo")
               
        Return JArray.FromObject(list) 'Return list
    End Function
[/CODE]